# Android Marshmallow permissions?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-runtime

I want to show permission prompt where user can accept the access of that permission,Like i want to access users contacts so i want to show prompt with two option allow and deny any example and source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
private void PerrmissionWork() {

    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("GPS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("GPS COARSE");


    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to "
                    + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            showMessageOKCancel(message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            requestPermissions(permissionsList
                                    .toArray(new String[permissionsList
                                            .size()]),
                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        requestPermissions(
                permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
    splashMainWork();
}

// mapWork();

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList,
        String permission) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message,
        android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", onClickListener).setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create().show();

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
        Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Initial
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        // Fill with results
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
            perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
        // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
            // All Permissions Granted
            splashMainWork();
        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(context, "Some Permission is Denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
        break;
    default:
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
    }
}
```

and call this method in on create like this..

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        PerrmissionWork();
    } else {
       splashMainWork();
    }
```

i am getting location in splash work method and using location permission you can use contact permisssion and in place of splash work do your contact code.. and there are lots of demo also available try google they can give you good explanations.. and there is very good explanation on developer sit too.
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) ..[Try this blog very helpful](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer ,working ..!!!

Comment: @NightFury.. my pleasure..

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html for the official documentation on requesting permissions.  Here is a sample class using that documentation:

```
public class PermissionCheck {


    private void requestIfNeeded() {
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
            String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    handleSuccessfulPermissionsRequest();

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    handlePermissionDenied();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    private void handleSuccessfulPermissionsRequest() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request Successful!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void handlePermissionDenied() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request Denied!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```