# Cannot Resolve Symbol Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, manifest, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am implementing runtime permission request for `Marshmallow` devices. I have set my build and compile `sdk` to `API 23`. Still `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` is not recognizable

Comment: try to clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had imported wrong package, the right package is

**android.Manifest**

Comment: I am already using `import android.Manifest;` but I still see the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE'`.

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to define `REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE`, since it is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098366/android-marshmallow-permissions/36098423#36098423)

As in 23 sdk you can not use dangerous permission directly from manifest you have do rum time programming for this else drop down your target sdk to 22.
[List of dangerous permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)